# Google Sheets pulling out specific data from multiple rows and columns to put into a logistic regression function

Tags: google-sheets, logistic-regression

I have a spreadsheet of multiple years of student annual writing assessment scores.

Each row is the data for one test (Test Year, Student ID, Test score with subsections, etc.).

I need to fill in each student’s data into a logistic regression model with the following variables:

SUMPRODUCT FUNCTION where I need the selected data to appear:

[Spreadsheet and corresponding cells needed in logistic regression function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHFKS.jpg)

B Constant Y3 -16.266  [Generate a number ‘1’ to balance the sumproduct function.]

B T1AvgScore    0.911   [Student’s first year test average score] I need a function to put the data here

B T3AvgScore    2.399   [Student’s third year test average score] I need a function to put the data here

B T3SF2     0.434   [Student’s third year subsection ‘Sentence Fluency (SF)’ score] I need a function to put the data here

B T3Conv2   0.251   [Student’s third year subsection ‘Conventions (Conv)’ score] I need a function to put the data here

y* = ln(p/(1-p))  [Calculated from the above sumproduct function]

p = exp(y*)/(exp(y*)+1 [calculation for the prediction percent]

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: To make it easier for others to help you, please share a sanitzed sample sheet, editable by all.

Comment: Hi kirkg13 here is a link to a sanitized sample sheet, editable by all https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hOb1ZLyV4XeXeOgBCvZEbTy3fNfbpRf43JDq2y5UJ5g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really contribute in trying to come up with the necessary formulae, given the very mathematical/statistical nature of you question.  If it is a matter of finding how to  pull the specific data values from your raw data into shape, to put into your formula, that would be easier.

Comment: But in your question, for example, you have "B T1AvgScore 0.911 [Student’s first year test average score] I need a function to put the data here".  Where does the 0.911 come from?  Are you asking us for the equation to generate that value?  And the same with all of the other values you are saying you need a function for.  Basically I don't understand statistics/math well enough to understand your question...

Comment: Hi kirkg13 thanks for giving it a go.  I have the numbers (like 0.911) from the logistic regression I ran in SPSS.  This issue is not really about the logistic regression, but about how to pull data from a string and place it in a specific cell....I was hoping the link to the picture in the original post may help with a visual representation of what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not clear if I'm answering what you're looking for, but I have the formulas that pull the Average Score values from the AWA sheet for a given student number.  See the tab I added to your sheet, Example-GK.

The query formula is simply:

```
=query(AWA,"select F where A = "&E$15&" and B = '"&D19&"' ",0)
```

where 15 is the specified StudentID (a numeric value, so no single quotes used), and D19 is the specific year.

I also added the ability to select the StudentID number from a dropdown list, in E15 on that sheet.  Or the StudentName could be used for the selection criteria, instead of the StudentID, if that was available and easier for you to use.  For now, the StudentName is ignored, since it wasn't available in the data.

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.  One issue is there might be more years of data for some students.  There are other ways of listing the years, which might help you.  I'll see if I can add that function.

**Update Sept 9,2020:**

If I've understood your comments correctly, and that for each model, there is a set of constants that apply to all students (see below for the Model 3 constants), then I may have a generic set of formulae that calcute the probabilities for each student, using all three models, provided there is sufficient data for that student.

[image]

See my updated Example-GK in your sheet.
And let me know if I still haven't understood how your final probabilities are calculated from the individual student data values.

Comment: Thank you!  I think this is the start in the right direction.  The next step word be when the student only has one or two years of data, the scores would be directed to a different model.  There is a Year 1 model with only one variable, and a Year 2 model with 4 variables....but I will look at what your provided and see if I can figure out more.......In addition, I would want a way for the student list to be dynamic, so I could get a range of calculations at one time, not always one by one student.  For example, I could generate a list of all students below 30% prediction of passing the test.

Comment: I've added a sheet called "Example-GK Experimenting"  Here I have put in the other two predictive models.  Ultimately, what I am trying to accomplish is for all students that have one year of test scores, the Model 1 is used to determine the prediction percent.  For all students that have two years of test scores, the Model 2 is used to determine the prediction percent. For all students that have three years (or more) of test scores, the  Model 3 is used to determine the prediction percent. I want to be able to look up individual or groups students based on filters of prediction percent etc.

Comment: @jamestoffee It should be possible to achieve what you've described.  I've added a column K to "Example-GK Experimenting" which checks how many years data for each student ID.  Then it is just a matter of selecting the right model formula -1, 2, or 3 - based on the number of years of data for that student.    What I don't understand is how you get the values in F6:F10 and I6:I10 based on the student's avg score each year - what is the formula for F11 and F12 based on the student raw data?

Comment: Thank you for the years formula.  
The values in F6:F10 and I6:I10 would be from the student database which has all the test averages and raw scores.  These are the significant independent variables in the logistic regression models.  The dependent variable was a Boolean based on if the student was ever able to have an average score of 4.0 or more on any writing test taken yearly [0 = no, never had an average score of 4.0 or more on any test; 1 = yes, had an average score 4.0 or more on one or more yearly tests....see next comment for more....

Comment: F6 = number ‘1’ to balance the sumproduct calculation, 1 * constant F7 = 1st test avg (the score range is 0-6)
F8 = 3rd test avg (the score range is 0-6)
F9 = Raw score for “sent fluency” from test 3 (score range 0-12)
F10 = Raw score for “conventions” from test 3 (score range 0-12)
Binary logistic regression model 
F11 = Constant: y* = ln(p/(1-p))
F12 = Independent variables: p = exp(y*)/(exp(y*)+1
Produce an output of the Bernoulli distribution 
Here's an article I wrote on part of this project
https://so05.tci-thaijo.org/index.php/thaitesoljournal/article/view/243465/165216

Comment: @jamestoffee See if my updated Example-GK tab is on the right track...

Comment: Yes! That's awesome!  It's definitely the type of calculations I was looking for.  I'll spend time exploring the calculations to get a better understanding of how you put this together.  I was trying to group data by students and found an add on that made the final display for users more user-friendly for the dashboard [see tab "More experimenting grouping rows"]

Comment: If it has addressed your issue, please select an answer as useful, so as to help others looking for something similar in the future.